# How to configure Visual Team Service(tfs) to clone a git local repository from specific branch?

Tags: git, tfs, version-control, azure-devops

How to configure Visual Team service(TFS) to allow certain people to create their repository from a specific branch not master?

The remote branches are:

Master Branch(2 branches)

- Test Branch
- Development Branch (2 or more features branches)

  - Feature A
  - Feature B

I want **developers** to only have access on **Development Branch** and **Administrators** to have access on **all branches**. Meaning when there is a new developer who want to clone the repository, he should get codes from development Branch(Which should become his local master branch).

Answer (score 1):

For Visual Studio Team Services, there isn’t the way to clone branch directly. Also, the Read permission (can clone repository) is applied to the repository level (https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/permissions#git-repository).

On the other hand, you can create a local branch from a remote branch.

For Git, we could clone a branch of repository by specifying -b argument (https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone).

Comment: hello; @starain , will cloning from a specific branch using -b argument only download the branch that's being cloned and restrict access to master branch?

Comment: @aidonsnous it can only download the specific branch files, but can't restrict access to master branch, users still can access to master branch and clone it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should be limiting access via the team functionality in VSTS, not git branches.

Create a new team or area for this developer, allow access to the node/branch you want him to clone and explicitly deny access to everything else. You can also set read only permissions to the rest of the code base if you want the developer to have visibility but not allow him/her to contribute.

This link should help https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/restrict-access-tfs
also https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/git/gitquickstart